# How do I make stacked barplot in R utilising three columns, I want to use the barplot() function

Tags: r, dataframe, multidimensional-array, bar-chart, visualization

I want a stacked barplot in R with year as my x-axis, percentage as my y-axis, and landuse as a colour fill. My data is given below

```
Year Percentage                    LandUse
1  2015       49.8                Agriculture
2  2012       51.2                Agriculture
3  2009       50.2                Agriculture
10 2015       22.5                    fishing
11 2012       21.4                    fishing
12 2009       21.9                    fishing
19 2015       14.7   services and residential
20 2012       16.0   services and residential
21 2009       17.1   services and residential
28 2015        0.8       mining and quarrying
29 2012        0.7       mining and quarrying
30 2009        0.7       mining and quarrying
37 2015        0.4  water and waste treatment
38 2012        0.5  water and waste treatment
39 2009        0.4  water and waste treatment
46 2015        0.8 Industry and Manufacturing
47 2012        0.8 Industry and Manufacturing
48 2009        0.9 Industry and Manufacturing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggplot2` package to plot stacked bars. Pay attention to that `Year` variable should be of `factor` type.
See the code below:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2012L, 2009L, 2015L, 2012L, 2009L, 
2015L, 2012L, 2009L, 2015L, 2012L, 2009L, 2015L, 2012L, 2009L, 
2015L, 2012L, 2009L), Percentage = c(49.8, 51.2, 50.2, 22.5, 
21.4, 21.9, 14.7, 16, 17.1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.9), LandUse = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Agriculture", 
"fishing", "Industry_and_Manufacturing", "mining_and_quarrying", 
"services_and_residential", "water_and_waste_treatment"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "10", "11", "12", "19", "20", "21", "28", "29", "30", 
"37", "38", "39", "46", "47", "48"))

df$Year <- factor(df$Year)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Year, Percentage, fill = LandUse)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Output:

[image]

P.S.
   If you want to use `barplot` you'll need to go through plotting value matrix creation, legend, colours etc (dozen lines of code). `ggplot2` gives it to you by default.